# What is the emacs/elisp equivalent of 'include'?

Tags: spacemacs, config

I added some `define-key` commands to the `dotspacemacs/user-config` function in `.spacemacs`

```
;; Fix SHIFT + arrow keys inside screen/tmux
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2A" [S-up])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2B" [S-down])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2C" [S-right])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2D" [S-left])
```

How would I include them directly from an external file which would be a plain text file, ie not a `.el` so it would be evaluated as part of the `dotspacemacs/user-config` function?

Comment: Why would you want to use a normal text file instead of an elisp-file?

Comment: By `include` I mean pure textual substitution, so if the command works as I expect the file name extension shouldn't matter

Comment: I know what you want to do (I'm a C coder) but I do not understand why you want to do it. I honestly think your concept is wrong. Have a look at here https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadingLispFiles

Comment: You want to use 'load'. I don't think the extension matters (if the file exists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `load`.

```lisp
(load-file "~/elisp/foo.el")
```

More ways you can find in the Spacemacs [configuration layer docu](http://spacemacs.org/doc/LAYERS.html).